# ASP.NET C# retrieve multiple value from database and add in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

How to add multiple column values from a SQL Server database and insert in `session[]`?

Just `FirstName` is working, when I add `LastName`, I get an error.

```
string constr = sql connection here.... ;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Email, [FirstName] FROM Personal WHERE Email = @email"), cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Email, [LastName] FROM Personal WHERE Email = @email"))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextboxUsr.Text);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextboxUsr.Text);
        cmd2.Connection = con;

        con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (sdr.Read())
            {
                string fName = sdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                //string lName = sdr["LastName"].ToString();

                string userFullName = fName;
                Session["New"] = userFullName;
            }
        }

        //con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `I add LastName is given error.` what error? did you notice that `cmd` does not select `LastName`? Why you have `cmd` and `cmd2`?

Answer (score 2):

### Step 01 : Read more about SQL and C# Basics

you need to read more in

- [SQL SELECT Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp)
- [.net - What is the C# Using block and why should I use it? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it)
- [c# - SqlConnection.Close() inside using statement - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588049/sqlconnection-close-inside-using-statement)
- [c# - var versus concrete type usage - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391896/var-versus-concrete-type-usage)
- [$ - string interpolation - C# Reference | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

### Step 02 : Use Select in a correct way

- change

  ```
  SqlCommand 
  cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Email, [FirstName] FROM Personal WHERE Email = @email"), 
  cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Email, [LastName] FROM Personal WHERE Email = @email"))
  ```
- to

  ```
  SqlCommand 
  cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Email, [FirstName],[LastName] FROM Personal WHERE Email = @email")
  ```

### Step 03 : read the full code

```
var sql = @"SELECT Email, [FirstName],[LastName] FROM Personal WHERE Email = @email";
using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextboxUsr.Text);
    using (var sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (sdr.Read())
        {
            var fName = sdr["FirstName"].ToString();
            var lName = sdr["LastName"].ToString();
            var userFullName = fName + " " + lName;
            Session["New"] = userFullName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do still need help ?